# JQuery uiLock from Google or Microsoft

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script tag in my HTML with the src tag pointing to "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js". That's how I access JQuery for my app. I don't have it downloaded and really don't want to. Now I have a function that is meant to freeze the webpage and block access to the UI for 10 seconds. I heard about jquery.uilock, and I plan to use the $.uiLock and $.uiUnlock function defined there.

Do I need another script tag? If so, what do I put under src? Does Google or Microsoft host jquery.uilock?

If not, what other options to freeze the webpage do I have? How do they work, and why are they better than the other options?

Comment: Another option is to add an overlay to your page (a mask) which will cover all the contents of the page. You can show it for 10 seconds and then make it disappear by setting it's display property. Here is an article that may help with the overlay (https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/), I use this type of thing when I want to show an ajax loader or something while the site is retrieving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [Download Section](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#download) of the jquery plugin?

There they say that the provide the js file here http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js

Comment: Yes, I was looking for it, but the tutorial I read suggested using a module called "jquery.uiLock". I figured blockUI was not the same thing, despite the similar name. So you're telling me this is what I was looking for?

Comment: It is one plugin of jquery which does what you want. I gess there are plenty of them out there. This one has a hosting of the resource. You can also look on sites like https://cdnjs.com/ to find a proper lb which you can reference instead of download

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm used to Python, so I thought JQuery was one thing with all these other packages underneath it. I'll give blockUI a try and report back.